# PDO not working - simply displaying some of the code as if it wasn't PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO, so I apologise if this is a silly question. I have two files: writel.html contains a simple form, with formaction="submitArticle.php" and method="post". submitArticle.php contains the following:

```
<?php

$con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysql','root','root');

$submission = $con->prepare("
    INSERT INTO sfWritings(title, summary, content)
    VALUES(:title, :summary, :content)
    ");

$submission_execution = $submission->execute([
    'title' => $_POST['title'],
    'summary' => $_POST['summary'],
    'content' => $_POST['content']
    ]);

if($submission_execution) {
    echo "article submitted";
}
?>
```

However, instead of getting either the echo message, or some sort of error, I simply get the whole code, as if it doesn't realise it's PHP or something:
[image: Screenshot]

If I add some html tags (`<html>`, `<body>` etc.) then it starts giving me this:
[image: Screenshot when using html tags]

The database is ok (I've been able to fetch some test data from it). And the way I'm doing the insert closely follows a (working) example for a tutorial. So I''m a bit stuck for what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: You have to execute it in your localhost server and not to open in through "file://"

Comment: Do you have php installed on the host system? Also the URL is accessing the page as a file not as a webpage.

Comment: You shouldn't immediately assume that it is a problem with pdo. If you just replace the code with `echo "hello world";` you will see that you have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not running this script on a server.
Just loading the file directly with the browser will never work.

Have a look at: https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html